# Kendo ui scheduler - How insert icon in confirmation button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

How do I insert icons in the delete popup confirmation buttons?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The is no special event in Kendo Scheduler that will be triggered when the confirmation Popup is shown so I would rather recommend handling the click event of the delete icon as for example it is done in this [dojo page](https://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/oSUKUSOs).